# How to keep my WebClient async download going after page_load returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

```
public class DownloadMyFileAsync{

    private WebClient client;

    public void DownloadFileAsync(){
        client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadComplete += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback);
        client.DownloadFileAsync("someurl.jpg","c:/somepic.jpg");
    }
    private void DownloadFileCallback(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e){
            //stuff
    }
}
```

In my webform:

```
static DownloadMyFileAsync downloader;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(downloader == null){
        downloader = new DownloadMyFileAsync;
     }
     downloader.DownloadFileAsync();
}
```

This sometimes downloads part of the file or sometimes nothing. When I debug and step through the code it seems to download the whole file. I'm guessing something is "destroyed" or cleaned up when the Page_Load method ends, so the whole file stops when Page_Load returns. How can I maintain the download?

Comment: Stephen Cleary covers it [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks), including pros/cons and the new `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: This is not [tag:asp-classic] will remove.

Comment: Some reason it won't let me remove it without editing the body of your post which I'd rather not do.